# Suggest a Chinese name to match my real name

Tags: names, surnames

I started learning Chinese and I am choosing my Chinese name. Can you suggest something that matches the etymology or pronunciation of my real name?

My real name is Wojciech Rogulski. My first name Wojciech is pronounced “VOY-chekh” and the meaning is “He who is happy in battle” according to Wikipedia. My last name Rogulski is pronounced “RO-GUL-SKEE”. The etymology is not really clear.

> The name is formed from two Slavic roots:
>
> - wój (Slavic: voj), a root pertaining to war. It also forms words like wojownik ("warrior") and wojna ("war").
> - ciech (from an earlier form, tech), meaning "joy".

[Wojciech - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wojciech)

Preserving etymology would be preferredd to only preserving pronunciation but it would be interesting to know all suggestions!

Comment: I suggest 羅衛權 (luó wèi-quán). 衛權 means "to protect rights/power",  the sound of 羅 is close to the letters "Ro" in your last name.

Comment: I thought 武 might be good for the "wój" part.

Answer (score 1):

罗飞琪 is not bad. 罗 is from "Ro"gulski, 飞(flying) is from VOY, and 琪(jade) is from chekh.

Answer (score 1):

罗威彻

罗：sound of Rog

威彻：sound of Wojciech

威 means Powerful power and awesome momentum
彻 means Govern
and 彻 is Emperor Wu of the Han Dynasty's name

Answer (score 0):

For the pronunciation of your first name, "VOY-chekh", a possible Chinese name could be 韦嘉 (wéi jiā), which has a similar sound and means "great and happy". The surname 韦 (wéi) is a common Chinese surname and has a similar sound to the first syllable of your name. The given name 嘉 (jiā) means "great" or "happy", which is similar to the meaning of your name.

For the etymology of your first name, "He who is happy in battle", a possible Chinese name could be 胜快 (shèng kuài), which means "victorious and quick". The surname 胜 (shèng) means "victory" or "triumph", which is related to the meaning of war. The given name 快 (kuài) means "quick" or "fast", which could be interpreted as being "happy" or "joyful" in battle.

For your last name, Rogulski, a possible Chinese name could be 罗格斯基 (luō gé sī jī), which preserves the pronunciation of your last name in Chinese. The surname 罗 (luō) has a similar sound to "Ro", and the given name 格斯基 (gé sī jī) is a transliteration of the "gulski" sound.

I hope these suggestions give you some ideas for your Chinese name!

Comment: Are you able to state what role ChatGPT played in generating this answer?  [Attribution is required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384648/351283) if ChatGPT-generated content is used.

Comment: @Becky李蓓 Agreed, suggesting a four character name for those prefering a name matching meaning is unexpected of a person to do, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

罗意杰

It sounds like Wojciech. You can understand it as “This is a person with the surname Luo who wants to be outstanding.”

Answer (score 0):

None of the sounds in Wojciech Rogulski exist in chinese, except for cie as che(pinyin).

I would recommend avoiding a fully sound based name unless you just want to go by your name in closest chinese pronunciation (just like people go by Lin Boli instead of choosing english name etc.)

For surname, lou(pinyin) is closest to the sound of the beginning syllable. This could be a good sound approximation for the surname since no meaning is attached to it-- an example last name choice would be 樓lóu, the rising tone is also somewhat similar to the tone of voice starting your surname. Alternatively a surname like 戰zhàn meaning battle could tie into the overall name-- pronunciation would be similar to dzien (with chinese pronunciation and tone).

For given name 兵歡bīnghuān could be a choice, individually the characters mean soldier joyous, referencing the happiness in battle of Wojciech. pronunciation would be similar to bęguą with different emphasis (and tone haha).

Hope this helps give ideas, I always recommend a natives opinion on names which I am not, just in case :)